# Censor rude words out from a string but not affect safe words

Tags: php, filter, preg-replace, str-replace

How can I filter out rude words without affecting words which are ok. Below in my example the word grass is being censored because of the 'ass' in grass. How can I change this code so that ass would be replaced with **** but grass would be unaffected?

```
$string = 'cut the grass spread the aftercut and watch the difference after a few days';

$naughtyWords = array("ahole","anus","ash0le","ash0les","asholes","ass","Ass Monkey","Assface"); //etc

$string = str_replace($naughtyWords, "****", $string);

echo $string;
```

results in

cut the gr**** spread the aftercut and watch the difference after a few days

Comment: This sort of thing never works the way you want, that's why you never see it in the wild, as it's futile.

Comment: Everyone gets past filters. I would like there to be better moderation, unless it's a kid's game, then there should be maximum filtering with maximum moderation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to check for spaces before and after the string in question.

Example:

```
<?php

$string = 'cut the grass spread the aftercut and watch the difference after a few days';

$naughtyWords = array("ahole","anus","ash0le","ash0les","asholes","ass","Ass Monkey","Assface"); //etc

foreach ($naughtyWords as &$word) {
    $word=' '.$word.' ';
}

$string = str_replace($naughtyWords, " **** ", ' '.$string.' ');

echo $string;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what Dave ment to say was :

You will need to check for spaces before each word in question.

```
$string 'cut the grass spread the aftercut and watch the difference after a few days';

$naughtyWords = array(" ahole"," anus"," ash0le"," ash0les"," asholes"," ass"," Ass Monkey"," Assface"); //etc

$string = str_replace($naughtyWords, "****", $string);

echo $string;
```

Or better still:

```
$string 'cut the grass spread the aftercut and watch the difference after a few days';
$patterns = array('/ahole/','/anus/','/ash0le/','/ash0les/','/asholes/','/ass/','/Ass Monkey/','/Assface/');
$string = preg_replace($patterns, '****', $string);
```